# Copying files to a USB drive

Tags: usb

Currently, i am trying to copy a directory with files that contain my works website from a Gentoo server to a USB drive.  Ive combed through many pages of you youtube and google and cannot seem to get it to copy. Im sure there is something im dong wrong here, anyone have any ideas?

`cp -r /opt/biweb/app/ /data/dev/sdb1/`

---

**Edit: mount points**

```
df-h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3  31G  31G  0     100% /
/dev/sda1  84m  9.5m 70m   12%  /boot

/dev/sdb1  68g 42g   23g   66%  /data
```

Comment: What happens when you run `cp -r /opt/biweb/app/ /data/dev/sdb1/` and what *exactly* do you want to happen? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 5):

The command you want is:

`cp -r /opt/biweb/app/* /dev/sdb1/`

Don't forget the asterix (*)!  The above command will copy everything in the `/app` folder into the `/sdb1` folder.

If you want to copy the `app` folder itself into the destination, then do:

`cp -r /opt/biweb/app /dev/sdb1/`

The above has no trailing slash after "app".  This will copy the `app` folder as well as its contents.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  You just remove the trailing slash and asterix from the source path.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately neither option worked. I first got "specified destination directory does not exist". Second i got, "no such file or directory."

Comment: Oh and it is mounted, its mounted on /data/. I must have something wrong along the way.

Comment: Correct, it's likely not `/data/dev/sdb1/` but instead `/dev/sdb1/`.  I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Apologies, I'm trying to learn this as I go for work. That didnt work either.

Comment: Please go into a terminal and type `mount`.  Then edit your question to copy and paste the output of that command so I can see what your destination should be.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did command, cp -r /opt/biweb/app /data, then pressed enter. Then there was no visible text after like to command lines available. What does that mean usually?

Comment: It means it worked, otherwise there would be errors.  `cp` does not output that the copy was completed successfully, only errors.  For future reference, please comment on your question, or on an answer instead of posting an answer to make comments.

Comment: Regular directories and files should not be copied directly to a block device `/dev/sdb1` . It can be used to restore from a cloned copy of the partition, but this is not the case here.

Comment: @sudodus I'm aware, it was originally `/data/dev/sdb1` but I edited it.  Regardless, I'm using an X destination just as an example, could also be `/foo`...

Answer (score 5):

The device description for the partition on the USB drive is

```
/dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, In your case it seems to be `/dev/sdb1`. But you should not write directly to the device. Instead you should mount it and write to the file system at the mountpoint. First you should create a mountpoint, or use one that already exists. Text after `#` is a comment (not used as a command).

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdn            # only the first time
sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt/sdn
```

or in your case

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1
```

**You may want to make sure that you are allowed to write to the USB pendrive from a regular user by the following method,**

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd1  # only if you want a new mountpoint
sudo umount /dev/sdxn   # general: only if already mounted (with bad permissions).
sudo umount /dev/sdb1   # example

sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general: mount
sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # example

ls -ld /mnt/sd1                          # check permissions

sudo bash -c "echo 'Hello World' > /mnt/sd1/hello.txt"  # test writing with sudo
cat /mnt/sd1/hello.txt                   # test reading (as user)
ls -l /mnt/sd1                           # check permissions of the content
rm /mnt/sd1/hello.txt                    # test removing (as user)
echo 'I am a user' > /mnt/sd1/user.txt   # test writing (as user)
```

**Edit 1:** Sometimes (I would even say often) the partition on the USB drive will be mounted automatically. You will find it with the following commands,

```
df -h
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

The automatic mounting may or may not make it read-write for the regular user, but it will usually be possible to write with superuser privileges, with `sudo`.

You can inspect how it is mounted with the command

```
mount
```

but it will display a lot of information (about everything that is mounted).

**Edit 2: copying command**

After finding out that the pendrive is automatically mounted on `/data`, the following command line should work, if [the partition in] the USB drive is mounted read/write and with permissions for your regular user ID.

```
cp -r /opt/biweb/app /data
```

It should create a directory `/data/app` on the USB drive with the content (the directory tree and the files). If it does not work, you can try the special mounting method, that I showed above, but modified for the current mountpoint,

```
sudo umount /data                                 # unmount
sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /data  # mount with 'full' permissions
```

**Edit 3: Please edit your original question, where you can use formatting tools.**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55910/discussion-on-answer-by-sudodus-copying-files-to-a-usb-drive).