# USB sticks are Read-Only in new installed Ubuntu 16.04!

Tags: read-only, usb-drive

I have a DELL Vostro 1015 laptop and just installed Ubuntu 16.04 upon. But I cant copy anything into USB flash memories! The "paste" option and "new folder" option don't work on USB flash memory!

I tried some solutions and commands I found on the Internet but they didn't work and one of them caused start up problems and forced me to re-installing Ubuntu!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903276/i-formatted-a-usb-drive-and-now-it-says-the-destination-is-read-only this might help

Comment: Thanks but my problem isn't for just one specific USB memory. any USB memory I tried have this problem!

Comment: What commands have you tried? what commands gave problems? the more information you add the more users will get attracted to the issue, so please add as much as you can. and have you tried `chown` ?

Comment: Yes I tried this but didn't work:
'sudo chown [username] /media/[username]

and

sudo chgrp [username] /media/[username]
'

Comment: Will the tips in the following link help you mount a partition in a USB stick with read and write permissions?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735 - Otherwise, please tell us what partitions there are (in the USB stick) by editing the original question with the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this guide I found it here: [How do I get permission to edit in my usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735)

> Mount a FAT32 partition in a USB stick with write permissions for
>   everybody
>
> Assumption: the pendrive is seen as /dev/sdx, replace the partition
>   device sdxn with the actual letters for the partition, for example
>   sdb1: /dev/sdxn ---> /dev/sdb1.
>
> Explanation: x is the drive letter, and n is the partition number.
>   Text after # is a comment (not used as a command).
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd1  # only if you want a new mountpoint
> sudo umount /dev/sdxn   # general: only if already mounted (with bad permissions).
> sudo umount /dev/sdb1   # example
>
> sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general: mount
> sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # example
> ```