# Unable to write anything into NTFS drives

Tags: ntfs

I have migrated from Windows to Ubuntu very recently. In Windows I had 3 drives and I am using the same here. I have installed my OS in one. I can't read/write or remove files/directories from either of the other two drives.

```
root@vishnu-desktop:~# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa3e0317f
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2           206848  314572799  314365952 149.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        314572800 1363148799 1048576000   500G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1363148800 3907026943 2543878144   1.2T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

In the above `/dev/sda2` is where I have installed Ubuntu.

In `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` I am unable to do anything.

Comment: do you have duel boot machine?

Comment: Even when you have `ntfs-3g` installed, there might be problems due to permissions. You can fix the permissions problems, if you mount with a command line (run in a terminal window). See the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/895733/copying-files-to-a-usb-drive/895782#895782

Comment: why do you want to use NTFS for these partitions? It seems like you are using a single boot system.

Comment: @Zanna: How did you reach that conclusion. There are 3 FAT or NTFS partitions on that drive that could hold a Windows installation.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster Obviously I'm assuming, but it's the way the drive setup was spoken about "migrated from Windows to Ubuntu"

Comment: @David : Yes. Since, i have migrated from windows it is the way that is been setup.  Now i can't remove/rename/copy/ any thing from one drive to another. Below is the error i am getting.

FYI... I have tried this as SUDO user.

vishnu@vishnu-desktop:~$ sudo -i
root@vishnu-desktop:~# cp /media/vishnu/DATA/Turbo\ C++\ 3.2.2.0
Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0/     Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0.zip  
root@vishnu-desktop:~# cp "/media/vishnu/DATA/Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0.zip" "/media/vishnu/LAB"
cp: cannot create regular file '/media/vishnu/LAB/Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0.zip': Read-only file system

Comment: It seems you have mounted the partition read-only. Please unmount it and mount it read-write (should be possible with the ntfs driver, that you have installed).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @sudodus: I guess i am a bit closure to the problem now. When it tried to remount it it says below. 

root@vishnu-desktop:~# mount -o rw /dev/sda3 /dev/sda3
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
root@vishnu-desktop:~# 

This is not a dual boot system. I have completely formated the drive where Windows OS is installed. So, can any one suggested me on what to do now?

Comment: After you formated the partitions, that 'belonged to Windows' (formatted in Ubuntu with a linux tool, for example `gparted`), they should be clean. If you used Windows, and Windows was hibernated or 'shut down for fast restart', you might still have the same problem. So try again, and you will find if the linux mount command will let you mount the partitions with read and write access. The mount command may bark, but it does not bite ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you have mounted the partition read-only. Please unmount it and mount it read-write (should be possible with the ntfs-3g driver, that you have installed).

- Unmount

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4
  ```
- Create mountpoints (only once)

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sda3
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sda4
  ```
- Mount the partitions

  ```
  sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=022 /dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3
  sudo mount -o rw,users,umask=022 /dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4
  ```
- Now you should have read and write access. Change directory to `/mnt/sda3` and `/mnt/sda4` and try to write something to the partition(s).
- See also this link,

  [askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735)

Comment: The partition may be mounted read-only as fall-back because of hibernation/fast-boot. In that case `mount -o rw` won't work and result in an error message.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, This is correct.

Comment: @VishnuvardhanCh, The way to fix it is to boot into Windows and *reboot* instead of shutdown (or turn off hibernate/fast boot in Windows).

Comment: I'd rather wait for OP to tell us how they mounted the NTFS partition and investigate potential errors before I give a recommendation.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Owl, I think this method solved the problem of the original poster, because the answer was accepted. I think *your* issue is different. I suggest that you **create a new question** and describe your issue with as many details as possible. Then it will be possible for many people to suggest a solution that solves your issue.